# Word for taking too much pride in something mediocre

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word, preferably pejorative, describing someone who take too much pride in something mediocre?

The reason I'm searching for this word is a good friend of mine constantly dwells on some small achievements, like he'd brag about how he could eat 5 burgers in 5 minutes or how he jogs to work everyday even though it only takes 10 minutes of walking to everyone we meet at the bar. So next time I see him doing that, I want to call him "Stop being (a/an) ____!"

Comment: I found this in Merriam Webster while looking for synonyms of "braggart"... Dig this: "Cockalorum".  I can't imagine anyone who wouldn't be insulted if you called them 'a cockalorum'.

Comment: H. D. F. Kitto quotes Theophrastus in *The Greeks* as calling this person "[the Petty Proud man](https://books.google.com/books?id=aoiihygkm6EC&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=%22petty+proud+man%22&source=bl&ots=UblVKKoYup&sig=qY4FJM-tUA-aYs7xYsqpsV8hcOA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IIBxVYfdOOuIsQShz5vYCg&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22petty%20proud%20man%22&f=false)". That name is not going to be understood by most people today, but I thought it might give some background.

Comment: @Oldbag sure they'd be offended but mostly because they wouldn't know what you've just called them.

Comment: To be fair, a burger a minute for five minutes straight does sound like something I, at least, couldn't manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vainglory, particularly the "inordinate" part of this definition, seems to fit:

> Inordinate pride in oneself or one’s achievements

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/vainglory

Comment: "Oh, stop being *vainglorious*."  Good one.

Answer (score 2):

How about **Boaster**

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Boaster

**Bragger** seems to fit too
And please do tell us about their response :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need a noun, then words like **show-off** or **braggart** may suffice. If you need an adjective, **smug** may help.

**Smug**

> Exhibiting or feeling great or offensive satisfaction with oneself or with one's situation; self-righteously complacent: a smug look; a smug critic.

[Ref: Free Dictionary](http://thefreedictionary.com/smug).

Answer (score 1):

This reminds me of the [**Dunning-Kruger**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) effect, in that your friend has an undo sense of accomplishment.

To imply anyone who is proud of their accomplishments is actually exhibiting the D-K effect is to imply that it would be difficult to be less accomplished.  They're so unaccomplished that *they don't even know what accomplishment is.*

Telling him he's being Dunning-Kruger would be a big insult.  But it may well go over his head.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest "self-satisfied" (excessively satisfied with oneself or one's achievements).

Comment: This doesn't express pride in mediocrity. It might (or might not) reflect a mediocre person being proud, but not necessarily proud of being mediocre.